# Displaying patient information in tabular form using OOP methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

I faced a difficult task for me, the condition of the problem is:
A class is required that will accept data: First name, middle name, and last name, Address, city, state, and ZIP code, Phone number, Name and phone number of emergency contact
You also need a class that will receive data about the procedure: Name of the procedure: Date of the procedure, Name of the practitioner who performed the procedure, Charges for the procedure

I sort of handled these classes, but I find it difficult to write a handler, please tell me how to implement a handler so that it displays information in this form?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOz0h.png)

My code:

```
class Patient:
    def __init__(self,fname,mname,lanme,zipcode,phone,addess,city,state):
        self.firstName = fname
        self.middleName = mname
        self.lastName = lanme
        self.zip = zipcode
        self.phoneNumber=phone
        self.add = addess
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
class Procedure:
    def __init__(name_proc, date_proc, name_ doctor, pay_proc):
        self.nameProcedure = name_proc
        self.dateProcedure = date_proc
        self.nameDoctor = name_doctor
        self.payProcedure = pay_proc
```

To be precise, the condition is worth it.:
Write a class named Patient that has attributes for the following data:
First name, middle name, and last name
Address, city, state, and ZIP code
Phone number
Name and phone number of emergency contact
The Patients class’s **init** method should accept an argument for each attribute.
Next, write a class named Procedure that represents a medical procedure that has been performed on a patient. The Procedure class should have attributes for the following data:
Name of the procedure
Data of the procedure
Name of the practitioner who performed the procedure
Charges for the procedure
The Procedure class’s **init** method should accept an argument for each attribute.
Next, write a program that creates an instance of the Patient class, initialized with sample data. Then, create three instances of the Procedure class, initialized with the following data
The program should display the patient’s information, information about all three of the procedures, and the total charges of the three procedures.

Comment: You do not seem to have made any attempt at displaying the information.

Comment: This comment is more destructive than constructive, I'm not the one to criticize you, but it seems like an exercise and just the grace of it is that you exercise your ability to be creative. Sorry if I offend you! but do not give up, try different ways to combine both classes in one or create a middle class ... if not the case, more apologies!